# How to customize/add logic in Strapi CMS Relation-Ship

Tags: sql, reactjs, strapi, headless-cms

I need your help in Strapi CMS.
my case is simple.

[image: Image description]
[image: Image description]

Here i made on collection type. that is called **Center** and next one is post.

[image: Image description]

here Center has many Posts relation.

### all centers title

- ind_chennai
- ind_goa
- ksi_mumbai

### some post content_title

- POST 1
- POST 2

[image: Image description]

When I add/edit a post, I want to show only any **center** title starting with **ind_** in the dropdown.

My problem is if I have to write the logic for this, where do I write it? if you know that way please tell me guys.

Details:

- strapi v4
- sqlite / psql